# Given an array of structs that all have field foo, is there an easy way to get an array of the foo values?

Tags: arrays, matlab, iterator

I'm using mksqlite to execute some SQL from Matlab:

```
myPeople = mksqlite('SELECT * from People');
```

With three rows in the People table, myPeople will be a 3x1 struct, containing three 1x1 structs, each of which has id, name, etc fields. What I want is an array containing the three id values.

In Python I would use a list iterator like this:

```
myIDs = person.id for person in myPeople
```

Is there a similar way in Matlab to extract all of the values for a certain field out of an array of structs with that field?

So far the best I have is:

```
myIDs = []
for x = myPeople.'
    myIDs = [myIDs x.id]
end
```

But that's probably pretty inefficient, because it's going to resize the array on every iteration, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myIDs = [myPeople.id]; %# nice shortcut syntax (horizontally concatenates)
myIDs = horzcat(myPeople.id); %# explicit way to horizontally concatenate
myIds = vertcat(myPeople.id); %# explicit way to vertically concatenate
```

See [this link](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/06/02/structures-and-comma-separated-lists/) for further reading on structures and comma-separated lists.

Comment: Ah, brilliant, the first one is exactly what I was after. And the link looks like what I really need to be reading. Cheers